# Sort Column in a file from high to low

Tags: python, file, sorting, text-files

I have a file which has a set of peoples scores. There are 3 scores for each person. I am able to display only the highest score of the person. However, I am not able to print to the python shell, the highest score in descending order. For example:

```
Persona    12
Personb    14
Personc    17
Persond    11
```

And I want it to be sorted into descending order of score. So it should look like:

```
personc    17
personb    14
persona    12
persond    11
```

So far I have created this code, however I do not know how to continue:

```html
with open("class.txt","r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    with open('class.txt','w') as fileout:
        for line in lines:
            fields = line.split()
            name, grades = fields[0], fields[1:]
            grades = [int(grade) for grade in grades]
            grades.sort()
            highest = str(max(grades))
            grades = [str(highest) for grade in grades]
            rows = filter(None, [line.strip().split() for line in open("file.txt", "r")])
            data = [(name, int(highest)) for name, highest in rows]
        for name, highest in sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1)):
            print("{0:s} {1:d}".format(person, score))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is as simple as:

```
from operator import itemgetter


rows = filter(None, [line.strip().split() for line in open("data", "r")])
data = [(person, int(score)) for person, score in rows]

for person, score in sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print "{0:s} {1:d}".format(person, score)
```

**NB:** This *assumes* that your input data is void of erroneous data and general garbage. If your input data is **NOT** clean you will have to expand this a bit further!

**Output:**

```
$ python test_data.py 
Personc 17
Personb 14
Persona 12
Persond 11
```

**Update:**

If your data has garbage in it like you describe in your comment.

```
$ cat data
Persona    12 foo
Personb    14 bar
Personc    17 baz
Persond    11
```

Then the above program would have to be modified slightly with a custom `key` for example:

```
def sortkey(row):
    return int(row[1])


rows = filter(None, [line.strip().split() for line in open("data", "r")])

for row in sorted(rows, key=sortkey, reverse=True):
    print "{0:s} {1:s}".format(row[0], row[1])
```

Which will still produce teh same output:

```
$ python test_data.py 
Personc 17
Personb 14
Persona 12
Persond 11
```

Comment: Theres an error that occurs on the data line, that says ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: I did warn you about the assumption of the data being **clean** and **exact**!

Comment: Oh, I fixed that problem but it still doesnt print in descending order. I have updated the code so you can see where ive gone wrong

Comment: If you want descending order pass in the *keyword argument* ``reverse=True`` to the ``sorted()`` function call. I must have missed that in your original question! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

To add to James's awesome answer, you can add a "cleaning" function that grabs only the first two items, checkout `take3()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def take3(a, b, *rest): return a, b, rest

rows = filter(None, (line.strip().split() for line in open("data", "r")))

data = []
for row in rows:
    person, score, _ = take3(*row)
    data.append([person, int(score)])

for person, score in sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print "{0:s} {1:d}".format(person, score)
```